# Hyper-V VM can't access docker container, e.g. RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, hyper-v

**Environment**

My dev machine is a VM hosted using Hyper-V the OS is Windows 8.1. Hyper-V is running on my local machine the OS is Windows 10. On the same host is RabbitMQ running in a docker container, to get RabbitMQ running i used the following command: `docker run -d -e RABBITMQ_NODENAME=bmorabbit --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 micdenny/rabbitmq-windows` I'm using Windows container for docker. 
Output of docker version is:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 22:19:00 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

And I didn't do any additional network configuration.

**Question**

I can access RabbitMQ from my Windows10 machine using the container ip address. To get this address i used `docker inspect rabbitmq`. When I try to access the same RabbitMQ from inside my Windows8 machine i will get a timeout error. Do i need to do some additional setup to get this running under Windows Container?

**What i have tried**

- The same configuration using Linux containers is running out of the
  box. So essential the question is what additional configuration
  setting is needed to run this under Windows Containers?
- Running the docker container dedicated to attach to a specific
  network, e.g. --network ="<networkname>"

Comment: Have you tried changing your vm settings to Network Adapter and bridge adapter?

Comment: Are you able to ping both the machine from one another?

Comment: I can't ping from vm to container. I can ping from vm to host and from host to container. And the network of the container is a nat. The VM has and external and internal virtual switch adapter.

Comment: Did you try exposing port?

Comment: Was this issue resolved? If yes, can you accept the answer and close this?